# apply дает ненужные нули

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть датафрейм, содержащий несколько столбцов с числовыми значениями и несколько ключевых для задачи столбцов со значениями 1, 2 или 3 [image: df]

Задача создать новый столбец, в котором будет число, являющеся комбинацией значений из 3-х ключевых столбцов. Т.е. если в столбцах ['R'] - 3, ['F'] - 1, ['M'] - 2, то в новом столбце значение этой строки должно быть 312.
Попытка сделать так:

```
def join_rfm(x): return str(x['R']) + str(x['F']) + str(x['M'])
df['RFM_Segment'] = df.apply(join_rfm, axis=1)
```

Выдает значения типа 3.01.02.0
В чём ошибка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создаем пример DataFrame для тестов:

```
In [27]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([1,2,3], size=(5, 3)), columns=list("RFM"))

In [28]: df
Out[28]:
   R  F  M
0  1  2  3
1  1  2  3
2  1  3  2
3  2  3  2
4  1  2  1
```

---

**Решения:**

**Вариант 1:** умножаем матрицу на вектор - этот вариант будет работать только если значения столбцов `['R']`, `['F']`, `['M']` состоят из одной цифры:

```
In [29]: df["RFM_Segment"] = df[list("RFM")] @ [100, 10, 1]

In [30]: df
Out[30]:
   R  F  M  RFM_Segment
0  1  2  3          123
1  1  2  3          123
2  1  3  2          132
3  2  3  2          232
4  1  2  1          121

In [31]: df.dtypes
Out[31]:
R              int32
F              int32
M              int32
RFM_Segment    int32
dtype: object
```

**Вариант 2:** склеиваем строки - будет работать для любых значений:

```
df['RFM_Segment'] = \
       df['R'].astype(str) + \
       df['F'].astype(str) + \ 
       df['M'].astype(str)
```

**Вариант 3:** склеиваем строки при помощи метода `.sum(axis=1)`:

```
In [32]: df[list("RFM")].astype(str).sum(axis=1)
Out[32]:
0    123.0
1    123.0
2    132.0
3    232.0
4    121.0
dtype: float64
```

метод `.sum()` предназначен для работы с числами, поэтому Pandas попробовал преобразовать результат к числовому типу. Если бы у нас были значения, которые невозможно преобразовать к числу, то Pandas не делал бы преобразований и оставил склееные строки. В случае числовых значений можно преобразовать все к целым значениям:

```
    In [34]: df[list("RFM")].astype(str).sum(axis=1).astype(int)
    Out[34]:
    0    123
    1    123
    2    132
    3    232
    4    121
    dtype: int32
```

**Вариант 4:** склеиваем строки при помощи метода [Series.str.cat()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html):

```
In [57]: df["R"].astype(str).str.cat(df[["F","M"]].astype(str), sep='')
Out[57]:
0    123
1    123
2    132
3    232
4    121
Name: R, dtype: object
```

---

**Сравнение производительности различных решений на DataFrame с 100.000 строк:**

```
In [35]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([1,2,3], size=(10**5, 3)), columns=list("RFM"))

In [36]: df.shape
Out[36]: (100000, 3)

In [37]: %timeit df[list("RFM")].astype(int) @ [100, 10, 1]
4.61 ms ± 9.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [38]: %timeit df['R'].astype(str) + df['F'].astype(str) + df['M'].astype(str)
222 ms ± 13.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [39]: %timeit df[list("RFM")].astype(str).sum(axis=1).astype(int)
263 ms ± 22.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [40]: %timeit df[['R','F','M']].astype(str).apply(''.join, axis=1)
3.1 s ± 17.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [59]: %timeit df["R"].astype(str).str.cat(df[["F","M"]].astype(str), sep='')
243 ms ± 34.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

самый медленный вариант по сравнению с самым быстрым:

```
In [41]: 3.1 * 1000 / 4.61
Out[41]: 672.4511930585683
```

Answer (score 0):

Или так :)

```
df[['R','F','M']].astype(str).apply(''.join, axis=1)
```

Comment: `df.apply(..., axis=1)` - ооочень медленно работает)

Comment: даже неприлично медленно :)